# Bison parser does not recognize alternative syntax

Tags: grammar, bison, yacc

I am trying to write a parser that recognizes a particular syntax. I am pretty far and most of the stuff works. I came across a problem with the Bison parser though when trying to enable it to recognize two similar but distinct constructs.
Here are the two constructs I want it to recognize:

```
type_1 IS ENUMERATION OF 
BEGIN
    element_1,
    element_2 := 4
END type_1;

type_2 IS ENUMERATION SIZE 8 OF 
BEGIN
    element_1,
    element_2 := 4
END type_2;
```

Basically this is for a enum like declaration that can be given with or without a bitsize parameter for the elements.

The Bison file I wrote contains two alternatives for the two versions. Each of them separate, when either being alone, or when it comes before the other one, works well. However when I put both description into the Y file, it only recognizes one of my declarations or the other.

Here are the lines of Bison code:

```
    enum_type : sized_enum_type                 { $$=$1; P3; }
          | nonsized_enum_type              { $$=$1; P3; }
          ;

sized_enum_type : identifier[L]             {P1(37,$L->Get_Line(),$L->Get_Column());} 
                IS[I]                       {P2(38,$I.ln,$I.clmn);} 
                ENUMERATION[N]              {P2(43,$N.ln,$N.clmn);} 
                SIZE[Z]                     {P2(42,$Z.ln,$Z.clmn);} 
                INTEGER_VALUE[V]            {P2(39,$V.ln,$V.clmn);} 
                OF[O]                       {P2(40,$O.ln,$O.clmn);} 
                TBEGIN[B]                   {P2(16,$B.ln,$B.clmn);} 
                enum_element_list[S]        {P2(41,$S->Get_Line(),$S->Get_Column());} 
                TEND[E]                     {P2(16,$E.ln,$E.clmn);} 
                identifier[R]               {P2(15,$R->Get_Line(),$R->Get_Column());}
                SEMICOLON                   {$$= new AST::AST_Type_Enum( (AST::AST_Code_Identifier *) $L, $V.value ); $$->_Set_Line_And_Column(  $I.ln, $I.clmn); P3;}
                ;

nonsized_enum_type : identifier[L]              {P1(37,$L->Get_Line(),$L->Get_Column());} 
                     IS[I]                       {P2(38,$I.ln,$I.clmn);} 
                     ENUMERATION[N]              {P2(39,$N.ln,$N.clmn);} 
                     OF[O]                       {P2(40,$O.ln,$O.clmn);} 
                     TBEGIN[B]                   {P2(16,$B.ln,$B.clmn);} 
                     enum_element_list[S]        {P2(41,$S->Get_Line(),$S->Get_Column());} 
                     TEND[E]                        {P2(16,$E.ln,$E.clmn);} 
                     identifier[R]              {P2(15,$R->Get_Line(),$R->Get_Column());}

                     SEMICOLON                  {$$= new AST::AST_Type_Enum( (AST::AST_Code_Identifier *) $L, -1 ); $$->_Set_Line_And_Column(  $I.ln, $I.clmn); P3;}
                     ;
enum_element_list   : one_enum                                                          { $$=$1; }
                   | one_enum COMMA enum_element_list                                   { ((AST::AST_Enum_Value *)$1)->Append( (AST::AST_Enum_Value *) $3); $$=$1; }
                   ;

one_enum    : identifier[L]                 {$$= new AST::AST_Enum_Value( (AST::AST_Code_Identifier *) $L, -1 ); $$->_Set_Line_And_Column( $L->Get_Line(),$L->Get_Column()); P3;}
           | identifier[L]                  {P1(17,$L->Get_Line(),$L->Get_Column());} 
             ASSIGNMENT_SHALLOW_COPY[A]    {P2(42,$A.ln, $A.clmn);} 
             INTEGER_VALUE[I]               {$$= new AST::AST_Enum_Value( (AST::AST_Code_Identifier *) $L, $I.value ); $$->_Set_Line_And_Column( $L->Get_Line(),$L->Get_Column()); P3;}
             ;
```

I dont think the C-statements on the right side of each rule part are necessary but I include them here nevertheless.

When I run the compiled parser on my sourcecode it complaints that it was expecting the token SIZE. When I exchange the rules for nonsized_enum_type and sized_enum_type (not the right side in the rule for enum_type, the complete source code order for the rules, move one rule below the other) then it recognizes the other form without size. When I include the SIZE 8 part in my code, then it complains that it was expecting the other form (OF expected).

So my question is: How is it possible to write a parser rule that recongizes both parts?

Shouldn't the generated code recognize that one rule is leading nowhere and then try the other one? It appears the second rule is never tried.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting all those mid-rule actions (MRAs) into your grammar cripples the parser. Since you don't include the definitions of `P1` and `P2`, it's hard to know why you need the MRAs, but it seems unlikely that it is actually necessary to, for example, execute a specific reduction action between the tokens `IS` and `ENUMERATION`, rather than executing the reduction action a bit later.

Specifically, the problem can be reduced to the following. Consider the two productions (only up to their first MRA):

```
sized_enum_type : identifier[L]     {P1(37,$L->Get_Line(),$L->Get_Column());} 
nonsized_enum_type : identifier[L]  {P1(37,$L->Get_Line(),$L->Get_Column());}
```

Each of those MRAs is implemented with a tag production. The logic of left-to-right parsing is that all reductions must be performed *before* shifting the next token. In both the above cases, the next token is `IS`, but seeing the `IS` does not clarify *which* reduction should be performed. As a result, bison will report a reduce/reduce conflict, and then choose the production which comes first in the definition file. The other reduction will effectively be eliminated, which makes the rest of its production unreachable.

The two reduction actions are, as it happens, identical, but *bison doesn't know that*. From bison's perspective, all MRAs are unique. In effect, the use of a MRA requires the grammar -- at least at that particular point -- to be LL(1), removing all advantage of the LR(1) parsing algorithm.

You could avoid this problem by left-factoring, but I'd strongly suggest that you try to rely less on MRAs. For building an AST, MRAs are practically never necessary, and they have a non-trivial cost as well as reducing the ability of the parser to cope with non-LL(1) grammars.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using these actions to keep track of the line/column as well as to push possible error codex on a stack so P1 and P2 basically call a global function that pushes errorcode 37 on a stack together with the lines and columns that the lexer reports (was hard to get that working at all). So the MRA are there to give me the best possible error message when parsing fails. So do I understand correctly that making the rules left associative would fix this? I only used the association keywords once to parse an assignment statement so I'm not very familiar with it

Comment: No, making the rules left associative won't help.

Comment: @herr_doktor: instead of using some homegrown location stack, use bison's builtin mechanism, which auromatically maintains a location stack parallel to the oarse stack. All you need to do is fill in a location object in your lexical scanner,

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to recognize this sort of construct with Bison then? I have to change the syntax so that the first keyword is distinct in both alternatives?

Comment: Oh and regarding the location stack you mention: I have searched for days in order to find a way to return the exact sourcecode location and I found nothing. I googled everything I could think of.  There were several posts here in SO regarding this problem and many people had the same problem to report the exact location of an error and the results were all halfbaked at best. I was finally able to put something together with lots of tricks in the lexer but if there is a built in way to retreive the line/column for a token, I wasn't able to find it

Comment: @Herr_Doktor: There's no problem parsing the construct. The problem is when you scatter your production with MRAs. As for location tracking, did you read section 3.5 of the bison manual (http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracking-Locations). If there is something you don't understand from there, I'd encourage you to ask a separate question, which would probably help other people as well.

Comment: Hm indeed. When I remove the MRA's then both my grammatical constructs are parsed. I can't say that I understand completely why but I guess this would require deeper understanding of the way bison works internally which I don't have, I'm merely using it at a casual level as a user, but at least I know a bit more. The problem now is of course to get error messages for parsing errors.

Comment: As for the location tracking, yes I read through all this but I can't say that it worked, and I'm not the only one with problems tracking the location. I got it working now but it is a while since I put that all together and since I'm not diving deeply into lexx/yacc I must admit that I forgot most of how it worked and what specific problems I had and the false attempts I pursuit, so giving the strict policy here I don't think I could ask a qualified question without getting deeper into that part of the lexer again.